# break list item in two columns on small screen in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

I want to break my list items into 2 columns on small screen but it must be in one column on md screen

```
<div> 
    <ul>
       <li> List Item 1 </li>
       <li> List Item 2 </li>
       <li> List Item 3 </li>
       <li> List Item 4 </li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to break list item from item 3 and item 4 must be displayed in second column in front of item 1 on small screen
output should be

- List Item 1   List item-4
- List Item 2
- List Item 3

Comment: <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">li 1, li-2</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">lii-3, li-4</div>

Comment: @MirzaObaid Did any of the solution worked for you?

Comment: not yet @swapnil your code is creating two different blocks of list i want just one list

Comment: @Kanudo no solution yet

Comment: what if using `position: absolute;` ? does it bother you?. If no, see: https://jsfiddle.net/nzcage/rooh60pf/

Comment: i need this view on small screen not not md and sm just on xs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```css
.clear-left {
  clear: left
}
.clear-right {
  clear: right
}
ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  list-style-type: none;
}
.block-1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.block-2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container block-1">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 clear-left">List Item 1</li>
    <li class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 clear-left">List Item 2</li>
    <li class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 clear-left">List Item 3</li>
    <li class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 clear-right">List Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container block-2">

  <ul class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <li>List Item 4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: its breaking but result is not as per required i want it to break from list item 3 and second column must start from list item 4 . first column include List item 1 , List item 2 and List item 3

Answer (score -1):

**Use the below code:**

```
<div class="row">
      <ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 firstCol">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 secondCol">
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
 .firstCol
 {
    padding-right: 0;
 }
 .secondCol
 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: but it is showing space between 3 and 4 i want them to like one list no space required

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
<ul class="row">
  <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
    List Item 1
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
    List Item 2
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
    List Item 3
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
    List Item 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adReKN